# How to position widgets using tkinter (entries,labels)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a GUI with Tkinter, such that you are at a grocery store, you enter the item, price, and quantity, and each item will appear on the top part of the screen.

I have a top and bottom frame, and when I place an entry it goes right in the middle of the bottom frame. I have tried justifying the position to the left, anchoring it, sticking it and doing whatever, but it's not moving.

This is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("project")
root.geometry("700x850+0+0")

textInput = StringVar()

class MenuBoard(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        mainFrame = Frame(self.master,bg = "white",width=700,height=400)
        mainFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        labelFrame = Frame(self.master, bg = "red",height=40,width=700)
        labelFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = N)

        welcomeLabel = Label(self.master, text = "",fg= "black",bg="red",)
        welcomeLabel.config(font=("Courier New",23))
        welcomeLabel.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = N)


actual = MenuBoard(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `foodItemEntry` object? If so, do you mean that the object, the `Tk.Entry` field is being placed in the middle of the bottom `Tk.Frame` and you would like to specify its position within the bottom `Tk.Frame`?

Answer (score 0):

-Use

```
bottomFrame.grid_propagate(False)
```

to expand the frame and

```
storeItemEntry.grid(pady=30)
```

Or whatever value you want for `pady`. You might have to give `row` and `column` numbers to `grid()` if you're going to place other widgets in `bottomFrame`.

You saw *"a strange dark grey background"* as mentioned in the comment because you gave `bg = "grey"` to  `bottomFrame`. The background wasn't visible initially because the frame shrank to fit the `Entry`. You can change the color to what you want or remove it entirely.

The following should be close to what you're looking for:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("project")
root.geometry("700x850+0+0")

textInput = StringVar()

class MenuBoard(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        mainFrame = Frame(self.master,bg = "white",width=700,height=400)
        mainFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        labelFrame = Frame(self.master, bg = "red",height=40,width=700)
        labelFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = N)

        welcomeLabel = Label(self.master, text = "Main Heading Here",fg= "black",bg="red",)
        welcomeLabel.config(font=("Courier New",23))
        welcomeLabel.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = N)

        bottomFrame = Frame(self.master, bg = "grey", height=450,width=700) #Change/remove bg
        bottomFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        bottomFrame.grid_propagate(False)

        storeItemEntry = Entry(bottomFrame, font=("Courier New",10,"bold"), textvariable=textInput, bd =4)
        storeItemEntry.grid(pady=30)


actual = MenuBoard(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

UPDATE:
Based on your comments, here is a rough implementation to work with.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("project")
root.geometry("700x850+0+0")


class MenuBoard(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        mainFrame = Frame(self.master,bg = "white",width=700,height=400)
        mainFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)
        mainFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        heading = "  Store Item".ljust(45)[:45] + "Item Price" # Pad the text with white spaces
        listHeading = Label(mainFrame, text=heading, anchor="w", font=("Courier New",14,"bold"))
        listHeading.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, stick="we")

        # Use Text widget so you can keep inserting items
        self.listItems = Text(mainFrame, font=("Courier New",12))
        self.listItems.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5, stick="we")
        self.listItems.config(state="disabled") # Prevents edits on the Text

        welcomeLabel = Label(mainFrame, text = "Main Heading Here",fg= "black",bg="red",)
        welcomeLabel.config(font=("Courier New",23))
        welcomeLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, stick="we")

        bottomFrame = Frame(self.master, bg = "grey", height=450,width=700) #Change/remove bg
        bottomFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        bottomFrame.grid_propagate(False)

        storeItemLabel = Label(bottomFrame, text="Food Item: ")
        storeItemLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.storeItemEntry = Entry(bottomFrame, font=("Courier New",10,"bold"), bd =4)
        self.storeItemEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15)

        priceLabel = Label(bottomFrame, text="Price: ")
        priceLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.priceEntry = Entry(bottomFrame, font=("Courier New",10,"bold"), bd =4)
        self.priceEntry.grid(row=2, column=1,)

        btn = Button(bottomFrame, text="Add Item", command=self.add)
        btn.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=15)

    def add(self):
        price = self.storeItemEntry.get() # Get item name from Entry
        #Get price, format name and price
        groceryItem = price.ljust(50)[:50] + "$%s" %(self.priceEntry.get()) 
        self.listItems.config(state="normal") # Enable edits on the Text
        self.listItems.insert("end", "\n   "+groceryItem) # Edit Text
        self.listItems.config(state="disabled") # Prevents edits on the Text


actual = MenuBoard(root)
root.mainloop()
```

A couple of things to note:

1. I removed some of your frames because they seemed redundant, you can add them back if needed.
2. Since you're working with a class, I added the `self` keyword to some of the attributes so I can use/call them later in other methods without errors. I left out the attributes that I do not need to call after creation.
3. `StringVar`/`textvariable` is not needed since you're updating the list with a button click.
4. There are lots of refinements I did not do (i.e. checking to see if a valid input is given before updating the list, ability to delete from the list, etc).
5. I used methods and features that you may or may not be aware of (`.ljust(50)[:50]`, `%s`, etc)

I hope this helps :).

Comment: `grip_propagate` enables the frame to change size to fit the child widget, changing it to `false` prevents the automatic change. You can add additional entries,  you just have to supply appropriate `row` and `column` numbers where you want them to be placed to `grid`.

Comment: You can read more about [grid_propagate here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method)

Comment: textvariable with StringVar lets you track changes to the Entry widget, or sets it content. [More from this link.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Yes, you can display the food item and price on the top frame. How do you want to do it? Do you want to display it after you click a button? Or you want to display it while it is being typed? I'll try to edit the answer to include that but you might have to ask a new question with details to the the exact answer you want.